# Magento 2 : How to send form data to admin email?

Tags: magento2, email

How to send the form data through email to admin I have created a form in the template and on submit click it should send data to the admin.

Comment: Just follow these steps  and add your post action with your controller name that is where you should write the send email code as explained here.
https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-send-an-email-in-magento-2/

Comment: in my action i have to write controller path of email right that is given in this tutorial

Comment: that code has error i cannot solve my problem