# send mail to admin gives error Invalid sender data

Tags: magento2

post.php

```
<?php
namespace Magneto\WholesaleApplication\Controller\Index;

use Zend\Log\Filter\Timestamp;

 class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_NAME = 'trans_email/ident_support/name';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_EMAIL = 'trans_email/ident_support/email';

protected $_inlineTranslation;
protected $_transportBuilder;
protected $_scopeConfig;
protected $_logLoggerInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
    array $data = []

    )
{
    $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_logLoggerInterface = $loggerInterface;
    $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();


    parent::__construct($context);


}

public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    try
    {
        // Send Mail
        $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        $sender = [
            'name' => $post['name'],
            'email' => $post['email']
        ];

        $sentToEmail = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        $sentToName = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);


        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
        ->setTemplateIdentifier('customemail_email_template')
        ->setTemplateOptions(
            [
                'area' => 'frontend',
                'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
            ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars([
                'name'  => $post['name'],
                'email'  => $post['email']
            ])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($sentToEmail,$sentToName)
            //->addTo('owner@example.com','owner')
            ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();

            $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Email sent successfully');
            $this->_redirect('');

    } catch(\Exception $e){
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
        exit;
    }



}
}
```

when i am sending mail to admin Invalid sender data is coming

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262622/magento-2-how-to-send-form-data-to-admin-email/262673#262673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your setFrom method. Change $sender to below code or try to print $sender to check if you can get Name and email correctly.

```
public function execute(){
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

try
{

    $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

    $sender = [];
    $sender ['email'] = $post['email'];                           
    $sender['name'] = $post['NAME'];

    $sentToEmail = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

    $sentToName = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);


    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
    ->setTemplateIdentifier('customemail_email_template')
    ->setTemplateOptions(
        [
            'area' => 'frontend',
            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
        ]
        )
        ->setTemplateVars([
            'name'  => $post['name'],
            'email'  => $post['email']
        ])
        ->setFrom($sender)
        ->addTo($sentToEmail,$sentToName)
        //->addTo('owner@example.com','owner')
        ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();

        $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Email sent successfully');
        $this->_redirect('');

} catch(\Exception $e){
    $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
    exit;
}}
```

Comment: name and email are the Names of input field of my form right?

Comment: and where to write above code please tell me

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Email template '' is not defined. now this error comes

Comment: Try this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262622/magento-2-how-to-send-form-data-to-admin-email/262673#262673

Comment: Follow this blog to create custom email template in your module.
https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-custom-email-templates/

Comment: @AshishRamchandani you should accept this answer for this error and create new thread for new one.