# Email template '' is not defined. in magento2

Tags: magento2

when I am sending a mail error Email template '' is not defined.is coming

Comment: Try this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262622/magento-2-how-to-send-form-data-to-admin-email/262673#262673