# How to send 2 different email from a single action in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

How can I send 2 different email with **different template** (one for client and second for admin) from a single action in **magento 2**

Comment: you can do this through event observer but you have to select observer depend on your action like in which action (ex: customer registeration, new order etc) you need to send additional email.

Comment: thanks, I am updating custom module (FAQ) and want to send email to both admin and client by using transportBuilder() but email is not sending

Comment: On your controller you would do something like this

public execute() {
  $this->customerEmail();
  $this->adminEmail();
}

protected function customerEmail(){
    //Customer Email
}

protected function adminEmail(){
    //Admin Email
}

Comment: Follow this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262622/magento-2-how-to-send-form-data-to-admin-email/262673#262673