# Magento 2.3 - Customer Email Tempalte is sent empty

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I have created a custom email template. I'm using transport builder to send the email, but for some strange reason the email is empty. To send email I'm using mageplaza-magento-2-smtp extension. Below my code:

> etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <newsletter>
            <referral>
                <invite_friend_email_template>
                    newsletter_referral_invite_friend_email_template
                </invite_friend_email_template>
            </referral>
        </newsletter>
    </default>
</config>
```

> etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="newsletter_referral_invite_friend_email_template"
              label="Invite Friend Email"
              file="invite_friend.html"
              type="html"
              module="Ped_Referral"
              area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

> view/frontend/email/invite_friend.html

```
<!--@subject {{trans "You have been invited to register"}} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<p>
    {{trans "You have been invited to register" }}
</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

> Controller action to send email

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Ped\Referral\Controller\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Ped\Referral\Controller\Customer;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Invite extends Customer
{
    private const XML_PATH_EMAIL_INVITE_FRIEND = 'newsletter/referral/invite_friend_email_template';

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var StateInterface
     */
    private $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * Invite constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        Validator $formKeyValidator,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $customerSession);
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Validate form key
     * @return bool
     */
    private function validateFormKey(): bool
    {
        return $this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest());
    }

    /**
     * Validate request params
     * @return bool
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    private function validateParams(): bool
    {
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');

        if (strpos($email, '@') === false) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The email address is invalid. Verify the email address and try again.'));
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Send referral email message
     * @param $email
     * @throws MailException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    private function sendMessage($email): void
    {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore((int)$this->getCustomer()->getStoreId())->getId();
        $templateId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_INVITE_FRIEND,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions([
                'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $storeId,
            ])
            ->setTemplateVars([
                'name' => $this->getCustomer()->getName(),
            ])
            ->setFrom([
                'name' => $this->getCustomer()->getName(),
                'email' => $this->getCustomer()->getEmail(),
            ])
            ->addTo($email)
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
    }

    /**
     * Send referral email message to customer's friend
     * @return ResponseInterface|Redirect|ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        if (!$this->validateFormKey()) {
            return $resultRedirect->setRefererUrl();
        }

        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');

        try {
            $this->validateParams();

            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $this->sendMessage($email);
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

            $this->logger->info('Sent referral email message to ' . $email);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Email sent successfully'));
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
            );
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('referral/customer/index');
    }
}
```

Why do I receive a blank email? (without subject neither body)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262622/magento-2-how-to-send-form-data-to-admin-email/262673#262673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I used:

> use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue\TransportBuilder;

instead of:

> use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

Comment: can you explain your answer how did you fix the issue?