# Magento 2 Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 277

Tags: magento2, email

Please Help me, I checked other magento stackexchange answer but not getting actual answer.
I am trying to send a email programatically then getting this error.
I am using magento2.3 version 
i got this error :- `Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 277`

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262622/magento-2-how-to-send-form-data-to-admin-email/262673#262673

Comment: not getting what they wrote

Comment: have you fixed this ?